# Simple Controller Rest endpoint test in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-restcontroller

I have been given a task to create a basic endpoint in java Controller. I came up with below.

```
@RestController
public class SimpleController{

@RequestMapping("/info")
public String displayInfo() {
    return "This is a Java Controller";
}

@RequestMapping("/")
public String home(){
    return "Welcome!";
}
```

}

annoyingly, it is so simple but I cannot think of how to create a ControllerTest, all I need is to test the code. This is all working and manually tested. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For a full system integration test over http, you can use the TestRestTemplate:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class HttpRequestTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void greetingShouldReturnDefaultMessage() throws Exception {
        assertThat(this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:" + port + "/",
                String.class)).contains("Welcome!");
    }
}
```

For a lighter test without actually starting a web server, you could use Spring MockMVC: https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
public class WebLayerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnDefaultMessage() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Hello World")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be useful to include that for JUnit 5 you'd use `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!